# Is there a way to use SmartSheet Control Center to bulk add reports to previously created projects?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I would like to bulk update Dashboards in SmartSheet, via Control Center, to leverage new reports I've created at the SCC/template level. I'm having two problems.

1. Is there a way to use SmartSheet Control Center to bulk add reports to previously created projects?  This article would seem to suggest there is -
   https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/71230/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-global-update-to-add-a-new-report-to-previously-provisioned-projects - however, I've been told by SmartSheet this is not possible.
2. At the same time, even if I manually create those reports, this Help article - https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/2479391-control-center-global-updates-dashboards - suggests that Global Updates will only recognize dashboards, reports and sheets that were created through Control Center.  So it would seem like a bad idea to manually create those reports because they would never "tie back to" to the template and be update-able by Control Center.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it has been a change in the last few days.

Documentation is correct Control Center can only add to new projects.

Unfortunately it is not possible, even the API has no report manipulation, not a simple copy or move it, nothing. I've been struggling with this issue for some time now, you can only do it manually.